# Problema com váriavel javascript com firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

Estou com problemas no javascript do `react-native`, preciso armazenar o retorno do `firebase` utilizando um `for` em uma variável e acessa-la externamente,porém o fato é que não está retornando nada.

```
export const atualizadorChamados = () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const emailCripto = b64.encode(currentUser.email);
    const ref = firebase.database().ref();
    let itensAbertos = [];
    let itensFinalizados = [];
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'carrega_chamados_abertos' });
        dispatch({ type: 'carrega_chamados_finalizados' });
        ref.child(`/chamados/${emailCripto}`)
        .on('value', (snap) => {
            itensAbertos = [];
            itensFinalizados = [];
            this.nomeResponsavel = 'Jurema';
            snap.forEach((c) => {
                firebase.database().ref(`/usuarios/${c.val().responsavel}`)
                .on('value', s => {
                        s.forEach((child) => {
                            this.nomeResponsavel = child.val();
                        });
                    });
                    console.log(this.nomeResponsavel);
                    if (c.val().status === 0) {
                        itensAbertos.push({
                            assunto: c.val().assunto,
                            data: c.val().data,
                            responsavel: c.val().responsavel,
                            status: c.val().status,
                            setor: c.val().setor,
                            id: c.val().id,
                            nomeResponsavel: this.nomeResponsavel,
                            _key: c.key
                        });
                    } else {
                        itensFinalizados.push({
                            assunto: c.val().assunto,
                            data: c.val().data,
                            responsavel: c.val().responsavel,
                            status: c.val().status,
                            setor: c.val().setor,
                            id: c.val().id,
                            nomeResponsavel: this.nomeResponsavel,
                            _key: c.key
                        });
                    }
                });
                dispatch({ type: 'lista_chamados_abertos', payload: itensAbertos });
                dispatch({ type: 'lista_chamados_finalizados', payload: itensFinalizados });
            });
    };
};
```

Continua retornando `'Jurema'` ao invés do objeto.

Comment: Olá @gustavo bem vindo ao SOpt, o código colocado parece esta incompleto e como você esta utilizando `this` fica um pouco mais difícil apontar uma solução. E recomendado você adicionar pelo menos o suficiente para um teste - [MCVE]. -- Sobre sua pergunta talvez você esteja tendo problema justamente com o `this` tente colocar `var self = this` no inicio e depois utilizar o `self` ao inves do `this`.

Comment: Obrigado @IcaroMartins, coloquei o código como sugerido, tentei fazer anteriormente com uma variável `let` comum, porém como não estava funcionando tentei usar o `this`

Comment: react ou react-native?

Comment: react-native, editado.

Comment: Acho que isso tá acontecendo pelo fato dos  métodos de leitura do `Firebase` acontecem de forma assíncrona.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso... Não tive tempo de executar o código... Pode ser que o código não funcione mas servirá de base pra entender como é feita a lógica

```
export const atualizadorChamados = () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const emailCripto = b64.encode(currentUser.email);
    const ref = firebase.database().ref();
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'carrega_chamados_abertos' });
        dispatch({ type: 'carrega_chamados_finalizados' });
        ref.child(`/chamados/${emailCripto}`)
            .on('value', (snap) => {

                let itens = () => snap.map((child) => {
                    let responsavel = null
                    firebase.database().ref(`/usuarios/${c.val().responsavel}`)
                        .on('value', s => {
                            //ESSA PARTE AQUI FICA DIFICIL DE ENTENDER QUAL É O DADO QUE RETORNA
                            // SE FOR UM OBJETO COM O NOME DO CARA PODE SER ISSO
                             responsavel = s.val().nomeResponsavel
                        })
                    child.val() && {
                        assunto: c.val().assunto,
                        data: c.val().data,
                        responsavel: c.val().responsavel,
                        status: c.val().status,
                        setor: c.val().setor,
                        id: c.val().id,
                        nomeResponsavel: responsavel,
                        _key: c.key
                    }

                })
                dispatch({ type: 'lista_chamados_abertos', payload: itens.filter(item => item.status === 0) });
                dispatch({ type: 'lista_chamados_finalizados', payload: itens.filter(item => item.status !== 0) });
            });
    };
};
```